# Python pylab, assigning text file into array with funny format

Tags: file, text, matplotlib, plot

I have some troubles trying to get the formatting right in order to plot this graph. this is what I have so far

```
from pylab import*

with open("spineprox.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()

data = data.split('\n')

x = [column.split(' ')[0] for column in data]
y = [column.split(' ')[0] for column in data]

plt.title("Plot title...")    
plt.xlabel('your x label..')
plt.ylabel('your y label...')

plt.plot(x,y, c='r', label='the data')
```

It then comes up with this error: `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 56.25   0.000000578`. I have no idea what this error means. Need help plz!

The formatting for the text file is like follows:

```
56.25   0.000000578 
56.2501 0.000003219 
56.2502 0.000007031 
56.2503 0.000001969 
56.2504 0.000005641 
56.2505 0.000006891 
56.2506 0.000008656 
56.2507 0.000005109 
56.2508 0.000007937 
56.2509 0.000006266 
56.251  0.000009547 
56.2511 0.000011828 
56.2512 0.000007297 
56.2513 0.000008641 
56.2514 0.000008969 
56.2515 0.000008234 
56.2516 0.000007984 
56.2517 0.000010266 
56.2518 0.000004594 
56.2519 0.000008469 
56.252  0.000006297
```

Comment: it doesn't look like that in the text file....

Comment: That's how you pasted it in your question. You can always edit you question.

Comment: when I switch them to rows, I get list index out of range.

Comment: Looks like columns delimited by tab, try ``column.split()``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the numbers are still strings, you didn't convert to float anywhere.

```
x = [float(column.split(' ')[0]) for column in data]
y = [float(column.split(' ')[0]) for column in data]
```

Don't reinvent the wheel though, much better option is to use `numpy.loadtxt` rather than parse the file manually.

```
import numpy as np
x,y = np.loadtxt('spineprox.txt').T
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: You don't need the split anymore. `loadtxt` will do this for you.

Comment: from pylab import*
import numpy as np

x,y= np.loadtxt('spineprox.txt')

plt.title("Plot title...")    
plt.xlabel('your x label..')
plt.ylabel('your y label...')

plt.plot(x,y, label='the data')

Comment: You forgot the `.T` as in the answer of Wim

Answer (score 1):

To read a text file, you can better use a builtin function instead reading and parsing it yourself line by line:

```
np.loadtxt("spineprox.txt")
```

See here for the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Then it becomes something like this, where you can access `x` and `y` as the columns of the array:

```
data = np.loadtxt("spineprox.txt") 
x = data[:,0] 
y = data[:,1]

plt.plot(x,y)
```

or as `x, y = data.T` as Wim proposed

Comment: data= np.loadtext("spineprox.txt")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loadtext'

Comment: its taking a while to load now. must be because there are so many values within this text file